# Accessibility: Rotate part of the screen

Tags: screen

I was hoping someone knows the utility/app, perhaps a macro that can help to rotate part of the screen.

Primarily I was looking in the Zoom option in Accessibility settings.

[image]

Zoom Style: Picture-in-picture

Now the only setting I am missing is if I could **change the orientation of the preview Picture-in-picture**. It is unfortunate that Illustrator doesn't support 'Rotate Artboard' function (Like Photoshop do Rotate Canvas) hence the question.

Anyone?